# Executable to launch an Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, rdp

I need to create tools so that a non-experienced/non-technical users can use (which means connect and start/stop) a Virtual machine on Azure. For connection, the RDP connection is doing a good enough job and is easy to take a hand-on. On the other side, to start / stop a virtual machine you normally need to access to the Azure portal which (on top of being not straightforward for a non-technical user) causes some access policy problems. One option could be to just let the virtual machine always "on" but then we are billed for 100% of time even though the user only needs it for a couple hours a week.

That's why I investigated the possibility to create a script that could be put into an executable file that would launch automatically the virtual machine by just clicking the exec. I have already seen this stackoverflow question : 
[Start azure virtual machine without azure portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182113/start-azure-virtual-machine-without-azure-portal)

which suggests to create an Azure PowerShell script that would start the virtual machine. Only problem is that launching a powershell script is out of the technical level of the person who would use it. On top of that, there is a need to install Azure add-on for powershell (if I understand correctly) which would not be possible depending on the machine and the rights the user have on it.

So my question : Do you have any idea on how I could make a simple program (in the form for example of an executable that would run on any machine without any dependency) that would start an azure virtual machine ?

One solution I thought about but it seemed very complicated : create a "super low cost" virtual machine that would be on 100% of time and just create an exec that instruct this VM to start the other virtual machine on demand ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can host PoSh scripts inside of Azure Functions now so that could host all of the logic for starting and stopping the respective services without the need for a VM running.  Functions can be triggered by hitting a url or initiated via something like a button click on a simple web page.  This is the scenario I focus on when supporting teams that need to provide automation to end users for things like lab provisioning/de-provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with the idea that a powershell script is outside of the scope of a user that can run an exe file. If built properly, a ps1 should just be a double-click, exactly like an exe.

Aside from that, you have a couple hurdles to look at.

1. Your user can't have access to the resources that they need to interact with. 
   This can be done by passing custom PScredential objects through the script and pulling the credentials from a file. You would build the credential file with [ConvertFrom-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/ConvertFrom-SecureString?view=powershell-5.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN) and then import it in with CovertTo-SecureString. The biggest problem with this is that if the user can see where that file is stored, they could potentially write a script to access that file and gain privileged access.
2. Your user doesn't have permission to run the powershell resources needed to execute the script. For this, you'd need to build in runas permission on the script, and I think creating an exe might be the best avenue for that. Although you could have the initial script call another shell with elevated permissions and work through that.

There are tools out there like PowerGUI, that will compile a ps1 file into an exe format. A properly compiled and secure exe file would hide the scripts that call out to secure string files and also allow for custom runas permissions built into the program.

Comment: thanks for your answer :
1) I agree that ps1 can be ran easily bu a non-experienced user by compiling it to an exe format
2) Nevertheless it still remains the problem of what happens if the user does not have powershell itself (for example MAC user) and does not have Azure addon for powershell ? Ideally I would like to have almost zero interaction with user environnement and setting
3) about building " runas permission on the script", I don't really understand how that could solve the problem, if the user does not have elevated rights to access powershell, it will not change it ?